# Commands and queries in PSQL are not running

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am studying PostgreSQL, and faced with the problem of output of the entered commands in the terminal.
Maybe I missed something before I started the queries.
Below, my actions are listed in the sequence:

1. I switch to the postgres user: sudo su - postgres
2. I enter the command to start the Postgres server: `pg_ctl -w -l /home/postgres/logfile -D /usr/local/pgsql/data start`

   In the terminal it looks like this:

   ```
    student@student:~$ sudo su - postgres
    [sudo] password for student: 
    postgres@student:~$ pg_ctl -w -l /home/postgres/logfile -D /usr/local/pgsql/data start
    waiting for server to start.... done
    server started
   ```
3. I enter the psql command in order to enter psql commands and write SQL queries

   In the terminal it looks like this:

   ```
    postgres@student:~$ psql
    psql (10.0)
    Type "help" for help.
   ```
4. Checking the connection to the server: \conninfo

   In the terminal it looks like this:

   ```
    postgres=# \conninfo
    You are connected to database "postgres" as user "postgres" via socket in "/tmp" at port "5432".
   ```
5. I enter the query: SELECT * FROM pg_tables LIMIT 5

   But I don't get any response.
   The same applies for a query in this format: `psql -c 'SELECT NOW()'; or psql -c 'SELECT * FROM pg_tables LIMIT 5'`

What I'm doing wrong is not clear to me.

Reinstalling postgresql did not help solve this problem. I tried to run postgres separately on a virtual machine, and the result is the same.

Comment: Put a semicolon ";" on the end of each statement in psql - statements can span multiple lines. I don't know what you are doing with psql on the command-line (the "-c" examples) - it ALWAYS prints something if it runs

Comment: @RichardHuxton I'm ashamed to admit :) but you were really right.
I didn't end the line with a semicolon and moving to a new line meant that PSQL was waiting for me to continue entering commands. Thank you.

Comment: @RichardHuxton But when I enter a command like: `pg_config --sysconfdir` , PSQL also does not respond. Postgre is installed on WIndows 10. And I know where this file is located in the Windows 10 directories. But I need to find it using PSQL. In this regard, the question arose of using the command to search for all configuration files.

Comment: You can type: `dir c:\pg_config.exe /s/b` on a command prompt, and wait for the answer. (There are other options too, but this one needs shortest explanation )   Output is (on my system): `c:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\15\bin\pg_config.exe`   (wait, you are on unix/linux....)

Comment: On Linux, you can do: `find / -type f -name pg_config 2>nul`  (Output (on my system): `/usr/lib/postgresql/14/bin/pg_config`)

Comment: `pg_config --sysconfdir` will not run inside the `psql` command line client as `pg_config` is a command line program on its own. You will need to run it from the Windows command line.